# Mac OS X: How to rebuild menu dependences

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsmenu

I have a weird problem. I submitted my app to be published on the app store, but they said me that I have to provide an open recent menu.

I know how to do it programmatically, but it doesn't work in my project because I deleted the File menu previously. I tried to create again this entry, but the instruction:

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] noteNewRecentDocumentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/pathToMyFolder"]];
```

does nothing.

I tried to use it in a new project and it works fine, but not in my current project.

I suppose I have lost my internal dependences inside the xml in my nib file.

Anybody knows how to rebuild them after creating the file menu entry?

Thank you.

NOTE: I work with Xcode 4, and my app is not a document based application.

Comment: iOS ,not IOS which is a Cisco software for routers

Comment: Why does this say IOS (which should be iOS as @dev remarks)? This is clearly a Mac question.

Comment: Sorry. I am currently working on another project, on iOS, and I got confused. Thanks a lot for mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Open Recent" menu has a hidden property that allows NSDocumentController to locate it in the main menu.

Xcode's "File >" menu template contains a standard File menu, including a proper Open Recent menu.

Locate the "File >" menu template in the Object Library, add it to your main menu, drag the Open Recent menu into your actual File menu, then delete the File menu template.

Comment: I tried it previously. Even I copied the entire File entry from another project. Also I created again my project, and copied the form recreating all its bindings, with same result.

Comment: I am thinking about creating entirely my project from scratch, adding all my files and frameworks again, but I want to avoid it if possible...

Comment: It was a problem with sandbox... another bug made by Apple. If your app has only read access, these instructions don't work.

Comment: @voyager — What kind of access did you have to grant your app in order to get this to work?

Comment: After changing it to read/write it worked. I reported this problem to Apple but I am still waiting for a response.